# Upon removal of an element from view, scope mode value is not consumed in other dom element

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

In my view I have two DOM elements, I removed one DOM element from the directive, which is rendered as another DOM element. it works fine when the removable dom is below the directive but it doesn't work when we exchange the positions of both the DOM elements. it shows in the view as {{data}}.

```
TypeError: b.setAttribute is not a function
at q.attr (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:132:20)
at Object.I.(anonymous function) [as attr] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:133:470)
at Object.Eb.$set (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:59:328)
at Object.fn (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:57:249)
at h.$digest (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:98:396)
at h.$apply (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:101:157)
at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:17:415
at Object.d [as invoke] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:30:295)
at Xb.c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:17:323)
at Xb (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js:18:30)
```

What can be the reason?

The following is the code which works,

---

```
<html ng-app="appPoc">
<head>
    <title>Angular directive scope POC</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var appPoc=angular.module('appPoc',[]).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.mainScopeVar="In the main controller scope";     
            $scope.anotherVar="New content";
        });
        appPoc.directive('stringDirective',function(){
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                replace : true,
                template : '<div>{{data}}</div>',
                scope : {data: "@data"},
                compile : function(ele,attr){   
                    var myele=angular.element(document.querySelector('#deleteme'));
                    myele.remove();
                    return {
                        pre : function(scope,ele){
                            console.log('in pre-link : '+scope.data);
                        },
                        post : function(scope,ele){
                            console.log('in post-link : '+scope.data);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{mainScopeVar}}        
    <string:directive data="{{anotherVar}}"><div>main content </div></string:directive>         
    <div id="deleteme">This gets deleted next</div> 
</body>
```

But when I exchange the positions of `<string:directive>`  and the `<div>` elements, like mentioned in the code below, it throws exception.

---

```
<html ng-app="appPoc">
<head>
    <title>Angular directive scope POC</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var appPoc=angular.module('appPoc',[]).controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){
            $scope.mainScopeVar="In the main controller scope";     
            $scope.anotherVar="New content";
        });
        appPoc.directive('stringDirective',function(){
            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                replace : true,
                template : '<div>{{data}}</div>',
                scope : {data: "@data"},
                compile : function(ele,attr){   
                    var myele=angular.element(document.querySelector('#deleteme'));
                    myele.remove();
                    return {
                        pre : function(scope,ele){
                            console.log('in pre-link : '+scope.data);
                        },
                        post : function(scope,ele){
                            console.log('in post-link : '+scope.data);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    {{mainScopeVar}}        
    <div id="deleteme">This gets deleted next</div> 
    <string:directive data="{{anotherVar}}"><div>main content </div></string:directive>         

</body>
```

Comment: you'd probably get at clearer error if you didn't use minified angular. Maybe try the non-minified and see if the error makes more sense?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you didn't handle a destroy event. Because jQuery's remove method clears out the data that is associated with the element to avoid any memory leaks.
A more detailed explanation can be found in this [Ben Nadel's article](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2706-always-trigger-the-destroy-event-before-removing-elements-in-angularjs-directives.htm)

> Ultimately, the order of operations in your AngularJS directive is important because of the way jQuery implements the .remove() method. When you remove an element from the DOM using .remove() or .empty(), jQuery will clear out the event bindings and the data associated with the element so as to avoid memory leaks. This means that if you remove the element before you trigger the "$destroy" event, the element will be in a "sanitized state" by the time your $destroy event handler is executed.

Basically, you need to add in your compile function (**before the action that removes the element**) something like this:

```js
scope.$on(
  "$destroy",
  function handleDestroyEvent() {
    console.log('destroyed');
  }
);

myele.remove();
```

Comment: I have 2 qusetions for the above answer. 

1. When you said adding the code in the compile function of my directive, did you mean adding it to the pre-link function inside the compile function?
2. I tried adding the code to delete the element `myele.remove()` in the pre link function, it simply worked without me having to trigger the "$destroy" event at all. So my question here is what did pre-link do internally?

Comment: 1. I ment in the compile function, above your myele.remove().

Comment: 2. the pre-link function occurs before the angular engine compiles your code. If you look at an ng-repeat for example, through the browser's developer's tool, (not at the code file on your computer), you'd see that it looks different, with comments. that an example of the compiling that the angular's engine does. so before the angular even knew what is the element you deleted and compiled it with the other code, you removed it. after the compilation it's a part of the angular structre and removing it confuses angular because it excpect it to be there

Comment: correction, the pre-link occurs after the code was compiled, but before it was **linked** to the data in you're scope. so angular still doesn't care if you removed it. the cimpile function occurs after the link and then removing it without alerting angular causes the problem along the DOM tree. so if the directive is after the element that was removed, it gets affected. to have a better understanding of the process, I recommand reading about the [$compile](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) service